# whatsapp cloud api template object issue to send from postman

Tags: json, api, cloud, whatsapp

[image]I'm trying to send the whatsapp cloud template from postman.
I created a template in whatsapp cloud with header media image,
body content,footer and two buttons.

the response of the templates when i use get api is as below

```
        {
        "name": "trns_btn_img_header_XXX",
        "components": [
            {
                "type": "HEADER",
                "format": "IMAGE",
                "example": {
                    "header_handle": [
                        "https://img.url.com"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "BODY",
                "text": "Body message"
            },
            {
                "type": "FOOTER",
                "text": "ftr optioal"
            },
            {
                "type": "BUTTONS",
                "buttons": [
                    {
                        "type": "QUICK_REPLY",
                        "text": "qrbtnone"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "QUICK_REPLY",
                        "text": "qrbtntwo"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "language": "en_US",
        "status": "APPROVED",
        "category": "TRANSACTIONAL",
        "id": "17XX209448XXXXXX"
    }
```

I tried the template json object in postman is as below

```
{
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "recipient_type": "individual",
  "to": "{{message_to}}",
    "type": "template",
  "template": {
    "name": "trns_btn_img_header_XXX",
    "language": {
      "code": "en_US"
    },
    "components": [
      {
        "type": "header",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "type": "image",
            "image": {
              "link": "https://img.jpg.com"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "body",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "Body message from pm"
          },         
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "footer",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "footer message from pm"
          },         
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "button",
        "sub_type": "quick_reply",
        "index": "0",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "btnone"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "button",
        "sub_type": "quick_reply",
        "index": "1",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "btntwo"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

the response error is "error": {
"message": "(#132000) Number of parameters does not match the expected number of params"

Comment: can you show the body text? did you added any parameters in body text?

Comment: I used only text as shown in screen like body message not used "{{}}" in cloud template

Answer (score 2):

Below object worked for me

```
{
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "recipient_type": "individual",
  "to": "{{message_to}}",
    "type": "template",
  "template": {
    "name": "trns_btn_img_header_XXX",
    "language": {
      "code": "en_US"
    },
    "components": [
      {
        "type": "header",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "type": "image",
            "image": {
              "link": "https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "button",
        "sub_type": "quick_reply",
        "index": "0",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "type": "payload",
            "payload": "btntwo"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "button",
        "sub_type": "quick_reply",
        "index": "1",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "type": "payload",
            "payload": "btnto"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure and correct the below things in send message endpoint request,

- Don't need to pass **body** component if there are no parameters in the body text, if there are parameters then you need to pass only that parameters text in the separate object of parameters in index order
- Don't need to pass the **footer** component because it is static when you create a template
- the **quick_reply** button type, use type as "payload" instead of "text" in parameters

  > ```
  > {
  >    "type": "button",
  >    "sub_type": "quick_reply",
  >    "index": "1",
  >    "parameters": [
  >      {
  >        "type": "payload",
  >        "payload": "btntwo"
  >      }
  >    ]
  >  }
  > ```